# How to dynamically add pivot item and add Image to each pivot item?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have an array of Image URLS .I want to dynamically add Pivot item for each image Url,  and add an image box to each pivot item to display the image .How can i proceed ? Please help.

Thanks and Regards

vaysage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not the recommended approach. Use data-binding instead.

make `arrayFeed` of type `ObservableCollection<Uri>`, assign it to `ItemsSource` of `mainPivot` and use `ItemTemplate` to customize your item UI.

### Example:

Code:

```
ObservableCollection<Uri> arrayFeed = new ObservableCollection<Uri>();
// populate arrayField
mainPivot.ItemsSource = arrayFeed;
```

XAML:

```
<Pivot Name="mainPivot">
    <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

--EDIT--

For your comment,

Generally, it is a good idea to use `ObservableCollection` while data-binding in `Silverlight`/`WPF`. `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface. It is helpful for notifying `UI` elements whenever items are added to/removed from `ObservableCollection`. That way `UI` can update itself.

Comment: can u please explain Why  ObservableCollection is used?

Comment: good idea, but shouldn't the item template contain a data template ?

Comment: Thanks for the codesnippet, but how do you bind to the pivotitem header?

Answer (score 6):

Atlast i found a solution .
Make all the image urls in an array(arrayFeed) and do as below.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < arrayFeed.Count - 1; i++)
 {
      PivotItem pivotItem = new PivotItem();
      pivotItem.Header = i.ToString();
      Grid grid = new Grid();                
      Image img = new Image();
      img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri((arrayFeed[i]));          
      grid.Children.Add(img); 
      pivotItem.Content = grid;         
      mainPivot.Items.Add(pivotItem);          
 }
```

Comment: Good job! Nice work, basic idea, every one should implement according to their logic, It solved my Prob... Thanks.